# Wordpress - Why are there comments when I have disabled it?

Tags: wordpress

I don't understand. I've disabled comments throughout my Wordpress blog, i.e. no one can submit any comments. Yet, there are still many spam comments in my database.

How do the spammers submit comments when there is no form for them to do so? More importantly, how can I prevent it?

Update: After lots of testing, I finally found the function that stops all the bot comment spam. The function is pings_open in comment-template.php. I add a return false to this function and all the spam comments are gone and real human can still comment.

Now, my next question is, what is the impact of disabling this function?

Comment: Are these comments still coming in? Or are they there from before you disabled comments?

Comment: Are these comments being published on your site? Or are they simply appearing in your Admin area?

Comment: @Noah - My comments is never on in the first place.

Comment: @Avinash - They only show in Admin area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spammersoften access comments.php directly. Start by ticking "An administrator must always approve the comment" in Settings ->Discussion. Then the best way to prevent spam comments is to use plugins like `Akismet`

Comment: Make sense. Let me try to rename the file and see how. Will update here.